# SQL Server Like Pattern

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, sql-like

I want to match custom pattern in one of the column in a SQL Server database. The problem is I don't know the exact pattern length.

I want only those rows which has 'function' and 'alphanumeric pattern' which has min 5 and max 8 characters. Starting and ending characters are not fixed, not case sensitive.

Column value looks like this:

```
Row    Value
--------------------------------------------------------------------
 1     I have a single own function and its namely 123BA689,BAS54256
 2     Everyone has base function AFD12,CHD12234
 3     Nicole has its own ASS1256902,25ADFG2
```

Desired output:

```
Row    Value
--------------------------------------------------------------------
 1     I have a single own function and its namely 123BA689,BAS54256a
 2     Everyone has base function AFD12,CHD1223465AS
```

I have tried `Like` and regex to match pattern but failed.

Does anybody know how to fix it?

```
select * 
from ab 
where lower(ab.a) like '%function' and '%[a-z0-9]{6}%'
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server doesn't support regular expressions.  You could *conceptually* do what you want with:

```
where lower(ab.a) like '%function%' and
      lower(ab.a) like '%[a-z0-9][a-z0-9][a-z0-9][a-z0-9][a-z0-9]%' and
      lower(ab.a) not like '%[a-z0-9][a-z0-9][a-z0-9][a-z0-9][a-z0-9][a-z0-9][a-z0-9][a-z0-9][a-z0-9]%'
```

However, this will return any string that has "function", because that is an alphanumeric patter with 5-8 characters.